# How do I solve the best predictor of X+Y given X-Y?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, predictor, moments

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, each distributed as

$$f_U (u) = p^u(1−p)^{(1−u)}$$

with $u = 0,1$; $U = X, Y$.
Find the best predictor and the best linear predictor of $X + Y$ given $X − Y$. Compute their respective mean squared prediction errors and directly compare them.

Comment: What is your definition of 'best predictor' and 'best linear predictor'?

Comment: Is this a homework question? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution is a Bernoulli distribution. It may help to tabulate the potential outcomes

```
X     Y    X-Y    X+Y   Prob
0     0    0      0     (1-p)^2
0     1    -1     1     (1-p)p
1     0    1      1     (1-p)p
1     1    0      2     p^2
```

I guess it is clear what your prediction of $X+Y$ is gonna be when $|X-Y| = 1$ (ie, the absolute value, $X-Y=1$ or $X-Y =-1$)

For $|X-Y| = 0$ you may also figure out a suitable prediction that optimizes the cost function (probably you are considering to reduce the expectation of the squared error).

The last step is to figure out the linear predictor. This would be easy if it would have been a linear function of $|X-Y|$, but you are looking for a linear function of $X-Y$.